Profile picture upload with user authentication
I've spend 3 days with this and I can't figure it out!!!
I've implemented a site with next js with autentication with auth js, prisma, postgres. That works.
I've also implemented a profile settings page with a form to change the user "name" and profile "image".
The "name" and the "image" uploaded via UploadThing both change upon saving the form, with the fields being changed in the database.
However, if i refresh the page the "name" field remains as expected but the "image" returns to the latest value (not the one that is in the database).
With Logout and then login in and refreshish the page results in the expected behaviour.
I can understand this. Is some cashing issue?, or Authjs? or_
Here is a snippet of the code (without the imports). I'm using shadcn for form.
export default function AccountSettings() {
  const user = useCurrentUser();

  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(user?.image);

  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

  const formName = useForm<z.infer<typeof NameSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(NameSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      name: user?.name || undefined,
      image: user?.image || "",
    },
  });

  const onSubmitName = (values: z.infer<typeof NameSchema>) => {
    startTransition(() => {
      console.log(values);
      setName(values);
    });
  };


  return (
    <section >
      <div>
        <div >
          <Card>

            <CardContent>
              <Form {...formName}>
                <form       
                  onSubmit={formName.handleSubmit(onSubmitName)}
                >
                  <div>
                    <FormField
                      control={formName.control}
                      name="name"
                      render={({ field }) => (
                        <FormItem>
                          <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
                          <FormControl>
                            <Input
                              {...field}
                              placeholder="name"
                              disabled={isPending}
                            />
                          </FormControl>
                          <FormMessage />
                        </FormItem>
                      )}
                    />
                    <FormField
                      control={formName.control}
                      name="image"
                      render={({ field }) => (
                        <FormItem>
                          <FormLabel>Profile image</FormLabel>
                          <FormControl>
                            {imageUrl ? (
                              <div>
                                <Image
                                  src={imageUrl}
                                  fill
                                  sizes="(max-width: 200px) 100vw"
                                  alt="profile image"
                                  id="image"
                                  key={Date.now()}
                                />
                              </div>
                            ) : (
                              <div>
                                <UploadButton
                                  endpoint="profilePhotoUploader"
                                  onClientUploadComplete={(res) => {
                                    setImageUrl(res[0].url);
                                    formName.setValue("image", res[0].url);
                                  }}
                                  onUploadError={(error: Error) => {
                                    // Do something with the error.
                                  }}
                                />
                              </div>
                            )}
                          </FormControl>
                          <FormMessage />
                        </FormItem>
                      )}
                    />
                  </div>

                  <Button type="submit" disabled={isPending}>
                    Save
                  </Button>
                  <FormError message={nameError} />
                  <FormSuccess message={nameSuccess} />
                </form>
              </Form>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}


I've tried to change the setName server action. but i think it is ok that
"use server"; //server action

import { z } from "zod";
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import { currentUser } from "@/lib/auth";
import { getUserById } from "@/data/user";
import { NameSchema } from "@/schemas";

export const setName = async (values: z.infer<typeof NameSchema>) => {
  const user = await currentUser();

  if (!user) {
    return { error: "unauthorized" };
  }

  const dbUser = await getUserById(user.id);

  if (!dbUser) {
    return { error: "unauthorized" };
  }

  await db.user.update({
    where: { id: dbUser.id },
    data: { ...values },
  });

  return { success: "Updated" };
};



If you doubt its cache, try appending a unique random parameter to the image url and see if it works. Its the simplest way to confirm a cache issue.

I've figure it out.
The problem was in auth.ts. I was not add the imagem field to the session.
I added to jws function:
token.image=existingUser.image
It was not a problem of caching.
